# VBA Access. Insert Into Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a listbox named listComponents1 and I want the items selected in this by the user to be populated in field Components ID of the table tblMasterData. In my table the field Components ID is of type number. I have written the code but I get an error saying syntax error in Insert Into statement. Can someone help with this issue?

```
For Each varItem In Me.listComponents1.ItemsSelected
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMasterData" & _
                "(Components ID)" & _
                 "Values(" & Me.listComponents1.Column(0, varItem) & ")"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field `Components ID` has a space so enclose in [ ]. Use `ItemData` to read value from list item.

```
With Me.listComponents1
    For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMasterData" & _
                    "([Components ID])" & _
                     "Values(" & .ItemData(varItem) & ")"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    Next
End With
```

Advise not to uses spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.